# ESLint: Require string-based enum keys to be sorted

Tags: eslint

Looking at the documentation for eslint [sort-keys](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/sort-keys) I can have Visual Studio Code report an error on line `a`:

```
const obj = {
  b: '2',
  a: '1', // not sorted !
  c: '3',
  d: '4',
};
```

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior for `enum`:

```
/* eslint sort-keys: "error" */
const enum obj {
  b= '2',
  a= '1', // no warning !
  c= '3',
  d= '4',
};
/* eslint-disable sort-keys */
```

---

Update: This may not be clear from the description of my question, but my enum is string-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys](https://github.com/infctr/eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys), more details about the rule [here](https://github.com/infctr/eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys/blob/master/docs/rules/string-enum.md).
I haven't tried it yet but it seems to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Not really a direct answer to your question, but with TypeScript you can achieve implicit ordering by not declaring all the values. For instance, according to [the official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) you can do:

```
enum Direction {
    Up = 1,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right,
}
```

And this will be implicitly sorted.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using TypeScript maybe it would be better to use [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) instead of ESLint.

You can still use some of your `ESLint` rules with [`tslint-eslint-rules`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-eslint-rules).

You can then add [`@crazyfactory/tslint-rules`](https://github.com/crazyfactory/tslint-rules) which has an [`enum-sort-keys`](https://github.com/crazyfactory/tslint-rules#enum-sort-keys) rule that does exactly the same as [`object-literal-sort-keys`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/object-literal-sort-keys/) but for `enum`:

```
// Passes:

enum Character {
  AAA = "aaa",
  BBB = "bbb",
  CCC = "ccc"
}

// Fails:

enum Character {
  AAA = "aaa",
  CCC = "ccc", <- The key "CCC" is not sorted alphabetically.
  BBB = "bbb"
}

// Passes:

enum Number {
  ONE,
  THREE,
  TWO
}

// Fails:

enum Number {
  ONE,
  TWO, <- The key "TWO" is not sorted alphabetically.
  THREE
}
```

Comment: Please note that [TSLint is deprecated](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) and ESLint should now be used for TypeScript projects.  [more](https://blog.palantir.com/tslint-in-2019-1a144c2317a9)